# How do I count multiple group by columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

first of all, let's say I have a table of user orders.

For example:

```
| user_id | created_at | order_data |
| ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
|   1     | 2010-01-02 |   {data}   |
|   2     | 2010-02-04 |   {data}   |
|   1     | 2011-01-02 |   {data}   |
|   3     | 2011-01-02 |   {data}   |
|   1     | 2011-04-02 |   {data}   |
```

Now, I'd like to count each month of every year, how many orders took place. Like, year 2010, month 01, count 1 order; year 2010, month 02, count 1 order, year 2011 month 01, count 2 orders ...

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried so far? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT YEAR(CREATED_AT) AS YEAR,
           MONTH(CREATED_AT) AS MONTH,
           COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_ORDERS
      FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY YEAR(CREATED_AT), MONTH(CREATED_AT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract year and month from the created_at and perform aggregation on that.

```
select year(created_at) yr,
    month(created_at) mon,
    count(*) no_of_orders
from your_table
group by year(created_at),
    month(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extract Year and Month from your "Created_at" column and then perform an aggregation on both of them

```
select year(created_at) as year,
       month(created_at) as month,
       count(*) as no_of_orders
from order_table
group by year(created_at),
         month(created_at)
```